# Laravel migration seeding on uppercase

Tags: laravel, migration, seed, capitalize

Running `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` which uses

**migrations-schema.dump**

```
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Questions`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `Questions` (
 `QuestionId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 PRIMARY KEY (`QuestionId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I get

[image]

It seems the first upper case letter in `Questions` is causing the issue.

Is there a way to overcome this? Unfortunately it's not possible to change it to `questions` since it's working as `Questions` on production.

Comment: you don't have access to your database server?

Comment: I do but as you may know, table names are case sensitive and I don't want to change all queries referring `Questions` table just so that the laravel migration tool works in local. I prefer to have the tool work with uppercases as well. Any idea?

Comment: not really, sorry